# Unable to install updates. Unmet dependencies icedtea-7-jre-jamvm and openjdk-7-jre

Tags: java, dependencies, openjdk

I am a newbie please help. Unable to install updates. Details shows:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
icedtea-7-jre-jamvm: Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2) but 7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 is installed
                     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 is installed
openjdk-7-jre: Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2) but 7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 is installed
               Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but 8c-2ubuntu7 is installed
               Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:1.1-0ubuntu15.4 is installed
               Depends: libgl1 but it is a virtual package
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

For Sun/Oracle java

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open terminal.

Add the webupd8team PPA repository and install Oracle Java 7/8 using the following commands one by one:

To install Oracle Java 7:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

To install Oracle Java8:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

For Openjdk:

Open Ubuntu Software Centre. Search 'Synaptic' and select 'Synaptic package manager'. FYI, Synaptic is the old package manager for Ubuntu and should take care of all dependency problems. After installing synaptic package manager, open it from Unity dash and search for `openjdk` and select `openjdk-7-jre` from search result.

BTW, its not clear what you are trying to install.